# android sqlite increment a column value

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to increment the value in a row by 5. I have searched here and Google but so far have not found and answer that works. Below is what seems to have the least amount of errors from Eclipse.

```
private static String[] table_scores = {DHObject.TABLE_SCORES,};
private static String[] column_tokens = {DHObject.COLUMN_TOKENS,};
private static String[] column_points = {DHObject.COLUMN_POINTS,};
private static String[] column_num = {DHObject.COLUMN_NUM,};

public Cursor onCorrectAnswer() {
    rawQuery(table_scores, [column_tokens = column_tokens + 5], column_num 0);
    rawQuery(table_scores, [column_points = column_points + 5], column_num 0);
}
```

Comment: You should post some more code. What does your `rawQuery` method do? What you have written isn't even proper java syntax...

Comment: Thank You for responding. I am very new to this and have been putting myself through as much training as I can find, which is  still quite lacking. Basically all I am trying to do here to increment or add 5 points and 5 tokens to the tokens tally. The tallies are in a SQLite table called TABLE_SCORES with _num being the key and a column for tokens and another for points. I have only one row which is row 0. I got the structure for this rawQuery from here but it had red lines under everything. I went to the SQLite sect on the android dev site and tried to structure the query from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To increment a column's values, you have to execute an SQL statement like this:

```sql
UPDATE Scores
SET Tokens = Tokens + 5,
    Points = Points + 5
WHERE Num = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you again. I'm a newbie, I have been using Lynda.com and The Busy Coder for Training resources. Apart from just getting on with it are there any other training resources you would suggest?. Kind Regards, Derek